# how to print array element from back side in increment loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

let suppose I have an array `var a = [1,2,3,4]` and now I want to print this array from the back side like `4,3,2,1`

I know this can we achieve by this

```
for(let i=a.length; i>= 0; i--) {
  console.log(a[i])  
  // output is  
  // 4
  // 3
  // 2
  // 1
}
```

but I want to print the output like `4,3,2,1` with the help of increment loop

```
for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++){
  console.log(a[i])
      // output should be 
      // 4
      // 3
      // 2
      // 1
}
```

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to do this ?

Comment: It is a very simple logical problem to start the i at the length -1 and subtract one each time.

Comment: In case it you have any purpose use console.log(a[a.length-1-i])

Comment: Not ever for loop has to be incremental.  And actually, imho, forcing all loops to be incremental reflects an inflexible approach to coding.  And given that part of the role of a developer is to examine issues and come to the best solution, being flexible is **very important**.  But I digress...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just take the length and subtract the actual loop value an one for zero based approach.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[a.length - 1 - i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is reversing the array prior.

```
a = a.reverse();
for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++){
  console.log(a[i])
  // output should be 
  // 4
  // 3
  // 2
  // 1
}
```

Comment: @CodeManiac If you have commentary on an answer, make it a comment.  Do not edit a question to inject your own statements.

Comment: @Taplar i thought it can be included in answer to make it more helpful for reader

Comment: If iagowp wishes to include your comment in his answer, it's his choice to do so.

Comment: @Taplar when we make a edit it says it will be updated when a peer review it ? it doesen't get updated until peer reviews it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit  Under the reason for editing, the closest one that matches your edit would be "to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it", however you didn't add clarity.  You added a potential counter argument.  Which is commentary. @CodeManiac

Comment: @Taplar my intention was to improve the answer that's it

Comment: If you feel I have incorrectly performed a rollback of a change you made, feel free to flag one of the comments for moderator review.  However, at this moment I do not feel further discussion on the matter will be productive.

Answer (score 1):

Just while we are solving problems in the most backwards ways...

```js
var arry = [1,2,3,4],
i = 1;
while (i <= arry.length) { console.log(arry[arry.length - i++]) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some complicated answers around here.  Why not looping in reverse order?

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(a[i]);
}
```